# How to remove gap for CSS Grid with height: 0 element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I recently started to use CSS grid.
I need to set an empty `div` element as one of the grid elements so that I can insert contents by javascript when needed.
The problem is that gap is applied to this element which is empty and `height: 0`. How can I avoid to apply gap only when the element is empty for CSS grid.

```html
<div class="container"> <!-- gap: 20px; -->
    <div class="grid-element--1">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element--2">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-element--3"></div> <!-- Need to appliy gap: 20px only when this element is not empty -->
    
    <div class="grid-element--4">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: replace it with margin-bottom

Comment: Do you need to hide it with height 0 or can you use display none? If this is a dynamic component, can you use js to change styles depending on content?

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch Thank you for the comment. I will use display: none in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap property is applied to the container. You can not set a specific gap for the children div, because it is a property of its parent.

What I would advise is to set your empty div, with the display:none property. And once you inject content to it with javascript, set its display to "block", "flex", or whatever display property it is using when visible.

Another solution would be to replace "gap" with margin or padding bottom on the children. And since this is a property of the children components, you will be able to make individual exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will use `display: none` and change the display property when I need to make it visible. In this case, to make it easy to have consistent spacing, I will stick to gap but good to know the other option as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been answered, I want to post a different way to react against a grid/flex gap when there's a case or moment in the flow of a website where we don't want it to affect some elements.

You can add a CSS class to the affected element(s) and use `:empty` to make it work only when they're empty (no text, no white space). Add a `margin-top` to that class with the gap's negative value.

So, for example if the gap is 20px:

```
--gap: 20px;

.empty-element:empty {
  margin-top: calc(var(--gap) * -1); // -20px
}
```

Empty HTML elements with that class will be pushed up the same amount of pixels as the gap, making it look like the gap prop does not have a visual effect.

I hope it helps!